# How to put arrows on Matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking to build a graph in Matplotlib with the origin centered and arrows on both sides of the x- and y-axes, and have been mostly successful in doing so with the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

plt.xlim([-100, 100])
plt.ylim([-100, 100])

ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

ax.set_aspect('equal')

for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(3)

# This part adds the arrows
ax.plot(1, 0, ">k", transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
ax.plot(0, 1, "^k", transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The problem is that I can't figure out how to add arrows to the left and bottom parts of the graph. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe use [plt.arrow()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html)

Comment: This worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add two lines:

```
ax.plot(0, 0, "<k", transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
ax.plot(0, 0, "vk", transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch):

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.xlim([-100, 100])
plt.ylim([-100, 100])

p1 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((-100, 0), (100, 0), arrowstyle='<|-|>', lw=3, color="k", mutation_scale=20)
p2 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0, -100), (0, 100), arrowstyle='<|-|>', lw=3, color="k", mutation_scale=20)
ax.axis('off')
ax.add_patch(p1)
ax.add_patch(p2)
plt.show()
```

It gives:

[image: arrows]

Comment: Thanks. The "<k" works, but the "vk" is misaligned with the axis.

Comment: @jleff It looks fine on my machine. In any case, I posted a different solution.